# Using guest VM's Ivy cache directory for dependencies from Eclipse on host

Tags: eclipse, sbt, scala-ide

I have a SBT project on VirtualBox virtual machine where I have installed SBT and have my project located. I run project through virtual machine with `sbt`, so all the external jars are located in `/root/.ivy2/` in the VM.

I have also mounted all VM drive with sshfs and routed to external jars from host as `~/dev/remote/project/root/.ivy/`.

I use Eclipse/ScalaIDE from host machine, so when I open project, the IDE can't find the external jars.

How to tell Eclipse to use these jars automatically or how to work with Eclipse and projects on VM?

Comment: Can you show how do you map libraries/jars in Eclipse to their corresponding jars on a disk? My understanding is that it doesn't really matter where the jars come from - a mounted (from host machine) or a local (native from the guest OS) disk.

Comment: The problem is that sbt command "eclipse" creates .classpath file with  path from VM /root, but eclipse IDE is run on host machine so the path is hosts path of mounted folder + path from VM. So, when I run "sbt eclipse" in my VM, it generates <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/root/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.akka/akka-camel_2.10/bundles/akka-camel_2.10-2.2.0.jar"/> but eclipse can find those jars only if I change it to <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/home/codez/Dev/remote/wm1/root/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.akka/akka-camel_2.10/bundles/akka-camel_2.10-2.2.0.jar"/>

Comment: For now I have to rename manualy all /root/ to /home/codez/Dev/remote/wm1/root/ in .classpath file every time I add new dependency so Eclipse can find it.

Comment: Could you remove the local Ivy2 cache directory with `rm -rf /root/.ivy2/cache` and create a *virtual* copy of it with `ln -s /home/codez/Dev/remote/wm1/root/.ivy2/cache /root/.ivy2/cache`?

Comment: I should've said...Could you remove the local Ivy2 cache directory on **host** (since the host is where you run Eclipse and the dependencies are on guest OS, on VM).

Comment: Link probably will work, if I put project in WM in another folder (not root), because now Eclipse need to be run as su to access root folder. But if there is, then I prefer more a solution that does not require to do anything in host machine. Any SBT parameter or solution that could change the way .classpath file is built.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sbteclipse was not created to support this use case.
It might be possible to tweak the sbt settings used by the `eclipse` command, but you will have to dig in sbt.

Otherwise, you can create a simple sh script to "fix" the file every time your dependencies change:

```
sed -i 's%"/root/.ivy2/%"/home/codez/Dev/remote/wm1/root/.ivy2/%' .classpath
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to either:

- modify ivysettings.xml with [the cache directive](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings/caches.html)
- change the sbt script to use the -cache directive
- change the java invocation to use the -Dsbt.ivy.home directive

To point to the mounted VM ivy cache